# IBM Mobilefirst 7.1 analytics logging

Tags: java, logging, ibm-mobilefirst, analytics, mobilefirst-adapters

I am using Mobilefirst 7.1 with Java adapters .I have read through the documentation for this version for operational analytics. The MFP sends the server generated logs automatically to analytics.
I see there are client apis for analytics logging, namely WL.Analytics.log(). 
But I have to send my java.util.logger logs to MFP analytics console, then what is the configuration required?
I have set my server configuration log level to INFO in server.xml and I have also put the jndi entry wl.analytics.logs.forward"  to true.
I see that the Mobilefirst generated INFO logs(com.worklight.common.util.HttpUtil) are sent to the analytics console.
But the java.util logs are not sent.
Please suggest how can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default only logging from package `com.worklight` is sent to analytics.

If you want your adapter, which is in different package, will send logs to analytics, you should set `wl.analytics.logs.packages` in **worklight.properties**.

Example:

```
#Capture logs from user defined packages (by default logs captured only from "com.worklight" package)
wl.analytics.logs.packages=my.package.com
```

Comment: Thanks Amichai..it worked . I think it should be also mentioned in the MFP documentation.

Comment: You are correct of course, we've opened a documentation task to add this.